# jaxws-maven-plugin wsgen IllegalAnnotationExceptions

Tags: web-services, maven, jax-ws, wsgen

I'm using clientgen to generate client-side classes from third party WSDLs. 
Then I'm using wsgen to create my web service, bundling up my classes, as well as the generated ones.

The jaxws-maven-plugin wsgen throws `JAXBContext IllegalAnnotationsException` complaining that the generated classes do not have a no-arg default constructor.

One solution that I saw on this site was to wrap the classes in `XMLWrappers`. Problem is the third-party classes are used in the third-party methods that I don't have control over.

Is there a solution or workaround for this?

Comment: Run maven with option --debug, and show stack trace

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround is to use the [axis2 maven wsdl2code](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/java/core/tools/maven-plugins/maven-wsdl2code-plugin.html) generators.

This will however generate a totally different client(still easy to use though).

The doc tells to add the following dependency as well:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.axis2</groupId>
      <artifactId>axis2</artifactId>
      <version>1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thank you. I did try that. I included these dependencies: org.apache.axis2: axis2
org.apache.xmlbeans: xmlbeans-xpath
net.sf.saxon: saxon8-dom
saxon: saxon 8.5.1
Now I'm getting an error .NoClassDefFoundError: net/sf/saxon/om/Name net/sf/saxon/om/Name

Comment: I added the dependency mentioned in the doc, I cannot remember adding any further libs. However I don't have a repo here. You can search for "saxon" and add it as well. It should be included in saxon 8.5.1 though http://www.jarfinder.com/index.php/java/info/net.sf.saxon.om.Name.

Comment: Thanks again. But ran into the same problem in the end. The generated classes don't have a no-arg constructor.

Comment: Finally resolved it by using jaxws-maven-plugin, <goal>wsimport</goal> to generate the 3rd party classes from their wsdls.